# Using jQuery Accordion, I can't figure out how to make each label appear as a different color/width

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

Pretty self-explanatory.  I used the tutorial from tympanus.net ([here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/02/21/accordion-with-css3/)).  I'm trying to make each label a different color/width, but can't figure out how to style that.

Comment: Show *your*, or at least *the*, *[relevant code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here*, don't just link us somewhere else on the internet. Have you made any attempts? What went wrong?

Comment: @Cosmos: there is no 'or,' the code should be here. A demo, JS Fiddle or any other, is nice to have but the code should be in the question. For reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link for the change everything:

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/rBxFj)
You can change `width` `margin` in this code

```
.ac-container{
    width: 400px;
    margin: 10px auto 30px auto;
}
```

You can change `background-color` in this code:

```
.ac-container label{
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #777;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    line-height: 33px;
    font-size: 19px;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 1%,#eaeaea 100%);
    box-shadow: 
        0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(155,155,155,0.3), 
        1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.9) inset, 
        0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

also you can change here for the `hover` `color`

```
.ac-container label:hover{
    background: #fff;
}
```